# MPAndroidChart - How to fix the zoom in the y-axis?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I using the [2.0.8 release of MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/releases/tag/v2.0.8)

When consecutively zoom in the y-axis, the y values are repeated.

I checked the sample project:

When normal display:

[image]

When zoom in the y-axis:

[image]

When zoom again:

[image]

And the same happens in my project, the values in the y-axis is repeated when zoom consecutively.

How to fix this?
By the time I do not show the y-axis in the chart.

Comment: Please check this issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32569618/mpandroidchart-how-i-can-limit-the-chart-zoom-in

Answer (score 2):

The reason therefore is quite simple. **The values actually aren't repeated**, however, they lack the number of digits to show you they aren't.

What I can recommend you to do is either:

- Set a `ValueFormatter` that uses more digits by default
- Create an intelligent `ValueFormatter` that bases the number of digits on the zoom level

The `ValueFormatter` that is created by default is not recreated upon zooming and therefore always shows the same number of digits.