# MpAndroidChart zoom String value error

Tags: android, zooming, mpandroidchart

I am using **MpAndroidChart** and it is going very well except for one problem. When I zoom in on a specific region of the graph, the X values appear multiple times in a clumped manner. I override the `X axis setValueFormatter` (code below along with some pictures) to display dates returned from inputted data. Has anyone had this happen to them, and if so, do you know the cause of it? I am considering just disabling the zoomable option, but I would prefer to have it. Thank You!

```
bottomAxis.setValueFormatter(new AxisValueFormatter() {
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
            // return values will all be the values of the dates array
            int value_i = (int) value;
            if (value_i % 2 == 0 && (value_i / 2) <= epochs.length && value_i >= 2) {
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(eu.getDailyInfo().getEpochValues()[(value_i/2)-1]);
                return (assignMonth(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)) + "" + String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
            } else {
                return "";
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getDecimalDigits() {
            return 0;
        }
    });
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could try adding `bottomAxis.setGranularity(1f); bottomAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);` to remove the extra labels when zooming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to remove the extra labels you can use the granularity feature. For example, if your bar chart is index-based, the following should work:

```
bottomAxis = mBarChart.getXAxis();
bottomAxis.setGranularity(1f);
bottomAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
```

Note: this is especially helpful for removing the duplicated labels when using a [`LabelFormatter`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38860000/5731450) or similiar in the new version `3.0.0` of this library.

Also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38739992/5731450) for more information on the granularity feature.